# Writing a python script to fetch content of a datastore entity in GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to fetch a column of a datastore entity in `Google Cloud Platform`. I can do it by writing a `GQL` query from the console, but I want to do the same using a python script and use the same GQL query and run it through the `cloudshell` of GCP.
Here is a table similar to the one used in datastore :

[image: The table named Person similar to datastore entity]

I have to find out the names whose Salary is more than 280000.
I wrote a GQL query in the console :

```
SELECT Name from Person where Salary>280000 ;
```

I got the result, but I want to do the same using Python script which could run in the `cloudshell`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its pretty simple.

```
from google.cloud import datastore
client = datastore.Client()
query = client.query(kind='Kindname')
query = query.add_filter('Salary', '>', 280000)
l = query.fetch()
l = list(l)
if not l:
    print("No result is returned")
else:  
    d = dict(l[0])
    print(d['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [Python client library for Cloud Datastore](https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/index.html).

You can use it to query data from a Python script, in your example it would be something similar to this:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
client = datastore.Client()
query = client.query(kind='Person')
query = query.add_filter('Salary', '>', 280000)
```

To learn more, I recommend you to take a look at the documentation for [queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries) and on how to [set up authentication](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication).